# Continous partial differentials implies $ f $ is countinuously differentiable

Tags: functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $ f\colon A\subset \prod_{i = 1}^n E_i\to F $ be a function defined on some open subset $ A $ of the product of a finite family $ E_1,\dots,E_n $ of normed spaces taking values in a normed space $ F $.

In what follows I define the *$ j $-th partial differential* of $ f $, for $ j = 1,\dots,n $, at a point $ a = (a_1,\dots,a_n)\in A $ as the unique bounded linear map $ \partial_a^j f\colon E_j\to F $ such that
$$
\lim_{\substack{\xi\to 0\\ \xi\in E_j}}\frac{{\lVert f(a_1,\dots,a_j + \xi,\dots,a_n) - f(a_1,\dots,a_j,\dots,a_n) - (\partial_a^j f)(\xi)\rVert}_F}{{\lVert \xi\rVert}_{E_j}} = 0\text{.}
$$

I'm trying to prove the following theorem. I'm not asking for a complete proof but only for some hint about how to proceed.

**Theorem**. Let $ n = 2 $ above (so that $ f\colon A\subset E_1\times E_2\to F $). Suppose the partial differentials $ \partial_a^1 f\colon E_i\to F $ and $ \partial_a^2 f\colon E_i\to F $ exist for all $ a\in A $, and suppose the functions
$$
\partial^1 f\colon A\to \hom(E_1,F)\qquad \partial^2 f\colon A\to \hom(E_2,F)
$$
taking a point $ a\in A $ to the corresponding $ j $-th pratial differential of $ f $ calculated in $ a $ are continuous, where $ \hom(E_j,F) $ is the normed space (under the operator norm) of all bounded linear maps $ E_j\to F $, for $ j = 1,2 $. Then the differential $ \mathrm d_af $ of $ f $ exists for all $ a\in A $, and the function
$$
\mathrm df\colon A\to \hom(E_1\times E_2,F)
$$
taking a point $ a\in A $ to the differential of $ f $ calculated in $ a $ is continuous.

*Proof attempt*. I thought that if $ f $ is differentiable then
$$
\mathrm d_a f = \partial_a^1 f + \partial_a^2 f 
$$ for all $ a\in A $, so I must in some way prove that
$$
\lim_{\substack{(\xi_1,\xi_2)\to 0\\ (\xi_1,\xi_2)\in E_1\times E_2}}\frac{\left\lVert f(a_1 + \xi_1,a_2 + \xi_2) - f(a_1,a_2) - \left((\partial_a^1 f)(\xi_1) + (\partial_a^2 f)(\xi_2)\right)\right\rVert}{\lVert \xi_1\rVert + \lVert \xi_2\rVert} = 0
$$
for every $ a = (a_1,a_2)\in A $, taking for granted the norm given on the direct sum $ E_1\times E_2 $ is the $ 1 $-norm. Maybe I can use the fact that
$$
\lim_{\substack{\xi_1\to 0\\ \xi_1\in E_1}}\frac{{\lVert f(a_1 + \xi_1,a_2) - f(a_1,a_2) - (\partial_a^1 f)(\xi_1)\rVert}_F}{{\lVert \xi_1\rVert}_{E_1}} = 0
\qquad
\lim_{\substack{\xi_2\to 0\\ \xi_2\in E_2}}\frac{{\lVert f(a_1,a_2 + \xi_2) - f(a_1,a_2) - (\partial_a^2 f)(\xi_2)\rVert}_F}{{\lVert \xi_2\rVert}_{E_2}} = 0
$$
and from there cook up some inequality (Indeed, I think this is exactly the idea underlying the proof), but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

**A rough sketch of the proof follows:**

You have to use the mean value theorem (in normed spaces):
$$
\begin{align*}
\|f(x+h, y+k) &- f(x,y) - \partial_1 f(x,y) \cdot h - \partial_2 f(x,y) \cdot k\| \\
&\leq \|f(x+h, y+k)-f(x+h,y) -\partial_1 f(x,y) \cdot h\| \\
&+ \|f(x+h,y)-f(x,y) -\partial_2 f(x,y) \cdot k\| \\
&\leq \|f(x+h, y+k)-f(x+h,y) -\partial_1 f(x+h,y) \cdot h\| \\
&+ \left\| \Big(\partial_1 f(x+h,y) - \partial_1 f(x,y) \Big) \cdot h \right\| \\
&+ \|f(x+h,y)-f(x,y) -\partial_2 f(x,y) \cdot k\| \\
&\leq o(\|h\|) + \|\partial_1 f(x+h, y) - \partial_1 f(x,y)\| \|h\| + o(\|k\|).
\end{align*}
$$
Since $\partial_1f$ is continuous, $\|\partial_1 f(x+h, y) - \partial_1 f(x,y)\| o(\|h\|) = o(1) o(\|h\|).$ You didn't specify the norm in the product but a good choice is $\|(h,k)\| = \|h\|+\|k\|.$ Then $o(\|h\|) + o(\|k\|) = o(\|(h,k)\|)$ and we are done.

**Note.** The form of the mean value theorem I was thinking of is (valid in Banach spaces)
$$
f(x + h) = f(x) + \left(\int\limits_0^1 f'(x + th) dt\right) \cdot h.
$$
You can the write $f'(x + th) = f'(x + th) - f'(x) + f'(x)$ to reach "Taylor's expansion of first order"
$$
f(x+h) = f(x) + f'(x) \cdot h + \left(\int\limits_0^1 f'(x + th) - f'(x) dt \right) \cdot h,
$$
call the right-hand most term $u(h) \cdot h.$ Then $\|u(h)\| \leq \int\limits_0^1 \|f'(x + th) - f'(x)\| dt = o(1)$ as $h \to 0$ if we assume $f'$ continuous. So, we can write
$$
f(x+h) = f(x) + f'(x) \cdot h + o(1) \cdot h,
$$
and by convention $o(1) \cdot h = o(\|h\|).$ (Let me add something interesting here. In probability we often use Taylor's theorem and this result shows that the reminder, written as an integral, is clearly measurable. Just saying if it ever comes up.)